# How to simplify object

Tags: javascript, react-native, simplify, code-cleanup, ecmascript-2016

I have an issue here where the code is quite heavy and quite hard to read imo.

I've simplified the code as much as I can but I was wandering if there's a way to simplify this code even further? Or maybe if there is any better terminology i could use for the comments? Any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance!

```
    const hourly = rateType[1] === 'Hourly';
    const daily = rateType[1] === 'Day Pass';
    const monthly = rateType[1] === 'Monthly Pass';
    const single = passType === 'single';

    // -- For all payloads
    const data = {
      booking_name: username.first_name + ' ' + username.last_name,
      number_of_people: numOfPeople,
    };
    // -- Hourly payload
    const hourlyPayload = {
      ...data,
      date: moment(mainDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      from: moment(timeFrom).format('hh:mm'),
      to: moment(timeUntil).format('hh:mm'),
    };
    // -- Daily or monthly payload
    const DayOrMonthPayload = {
      ...data,
      start_date: moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      end_date: moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    };
    // -- Single day payload
    const singleDayPayload = {
      ...data,
      dates: [moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')],
    };

 // -- // CREATE_BOOKING_FN // -- //
    if (rateType) {
      setLoading(true);
      hourly // --||-- Hourly Action --||-- \\
        ? await addToCart(hourlyPayload, 'hourly', id, cartItems, () =>
            _handleAdded(
              fastCheckout ? fastCheckout : null,
              cb ? () => cb() : null,
            ),
          )
        : daily // --||-- Daily Action  --||-- \\
        ? await addToCart(
            single ? singleDayPayload : DayOrMonthPayload,
            single ? 'individual-dates' : 'daily',
            id,
            cartItems,
            () =>
              _handleAdded(
                fastCheckout ? fastCheckout : null,
                cb ? () => cb() : console.log('null'),
              ),
          )
        : monthly // --||-- Monthly Action  --||-- \\
        ? await addToCart(DayOrMonthPayload, 'monthly', id, cartItems, () =>
            _handleAdded(
              fastCheckout ? fastCheckout : null,
              cb ? () => cb() : console.log('null'),
            ),
          )
        : null;
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      alert('Please select a rate');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to simplify `booking_name`

```js
booking_name: `${username.first_name} ${username.last_name}`,
```

Also consistency in variable names would better, you could choose one of the variable naming styles, snake_case or camelCase.

Also now you can shorten expression `key:value` [even more](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/object-literal-extensions/).

```js
const data = {
  booking_name: `${username.first_name} ${username.last_name}`,
  number_of_people,
};
```

Also that ternary expression is very hard to read, I think `switch case` would better.

```js
switch (type_of_date) {
  case hourly:
      ...
  case daily:
      ...
  case monthly:
      ...
  default:
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using functions for avoiding repetition and creating data. Here we have a basic `Booking` object that can be used to construct all varieties of bookings. Fill in `___` as you see fit -

```js
function Booking(type, ___) {
  switch (type) {
    case "Hourly"
      return { ...Party(___), ...Hourly(___) }
    case "DayOrMonth":
      return { ...Party(___), ...DayOrMonth(___) }
    case Single:
      return { ...Party(___), ...Single(___) }
    default:
      throw Error("invalid booking type: " + type)
  }
}
```

In the function above it's plain to see that each output has `Party` information associated -

```js
function Party(user, number_of_people) {
  return {
    name: user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
    number_of_people
  }
}
```

Here are the booking types, `Hourly`, `DayOrMonth` and `Single` -

```js
function Hourly(date, from, to) {
  return {
    date: mDate(date),
    from: mTime(from),
    to: mTime(to)
  }
}
```

```js
function DayOrMonth(start, end) {
  return {
    start: mDate(start),
    end: mDate(end)
  }
}

function Single(date) {
  return {
    date: mDate(date)
  }
}
```

We avoid repetition of `moment(...).format(...)` and ensure consistency with `mDate` and `mTime` -

```js
function mDate(t) {
  return moment(t).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
}

function mTime(t) {
  return moment(t).format("hh:mm")
}
```